# Google App Script how to load different pages using HTML Service?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

How do I load different pages in doGet with HTML Service programmatically?  If it is impossible, why GAS editor allows creating different HTML pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your loading different pages based on parameters passed in the URL you can test for the parameter using

```
function doGet(e) {
   if (e.parameter.messageID) {   // Simply test if the parm messageID exists
```

You can always do something like this too

```
switch (v) {
   case "A":   var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("A");  break;
   case "B":   var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("B");  break;
}
return t.evaluate();
```

And my final option is you can put conditional logic into the template to get different HTML

```
 // GAS file
 var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("A");
 var v = "A";   
 t.v = v;  // pass the variable v to the template 
 return t.evaluate();

 // A.html template file
 <? if (v == "A") { ?>
    <b>a bold A</b>
 <? } else { ?>
    <b>not a A but bold anyway </b>
 <? } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  So if I load index.html at first, then how do I reload the doGet in order to reevaluate the condition you have above?